# Migrating from Qt4 to Qt5: no matching function

Tags: qt4, migration, qt5

I've got a compile-time error when building Qt4 project with Qt5:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QPrintPreviewWidget*, const char*, MainWindow*, const char*)'
         connect( dlgPrintPreview.previewWidget(), SIGNAL( paintRequested( QPrinter* ) ), this, SLOT( printConflictReport( QPrinter* ) ) );
                                                                                                                                         ^
...

C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:196:36: note: static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)
     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal,
                                    ^
C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:196:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QPrintPreviewWidget*' to 'const QObject*'
```

I included **printsupport** and **widgets** in **.pro** file, replaced **QtGui** with **QtWidget** - nothing helps!
What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated

Comment: Missing `#include <QPrintPreviewWidget>`?

Comment: YEAH!!! Thank you very much, @peppe - I included **QPrintPreviewWidget** into MainWindow.cpp and it fixed the problem!

Comment: Learn to read the compiler's error. It's not saying that it doesn't know about QPrintPreviewWidget, it's saying that it can't convert a `QPrintPreviewWidget*` to a `const QObject*`. Now the const-conversion is for free, but how comes that the other conversion is not possible, given that `QObject` is a public base of `QPrintPreviewWidget`? It means that the compiler doesn't know that `QObject` is a base. So the compiler has not seen `QPrintPreviewWidget` definition. So an include is missing.

Comment: Thank you one more time @peppe, but I did not get how the following situation was possible (compilation without any error) when using **Qt4**:  
1. In file **printpreviewdialog.h**:  
    `QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE  
    class QPrintPreviewWidget;  
    QT_END_NAMESPACE`  
2. In file **mainwindow.cpp**:  
    `#include "printpreviewdialog.h`

can't insert line breaks in comment, sorry :(

Comment: Maybe some other header included that one (so you would indirectly include that). Who knows. Qt doesn't guarantee source compatibility if you don't include the right include for the things you use :)